# PHP - Checking if date is passed timezone issue

Tags: php, datetime

I am struggling to check if a date has passed in PHP due to timezone discrepancies. The date I am wanting to check against is returned in the format **yyyymmdd**. The first thing I tried was the following:

```
$date = new DateTime('20240116');
$now = new DateTime();

if ($date < $now) :
    echo 'Date has passed';
endif;
```

This works for the most part, but there's a 5 hour window where the date is incorrectly reporting having past due to `DateTime` returning in `UTC` and I am wanting it to check against Eastern time.

I tried to rectify this by specifying a timezone:

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
```

But this doesn't seem to work either. Even though the date that's being passed into `$date` is `20240116`, it is being returned as the 15th:

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2024-01-15 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/New_York )
```

How can I ensure that the conditional will only return true if the date has passed in Eastern time?

Comment: Try passing the `DateTimeZone` as the 2nd parameter to the `DateTime()` constructor

Comment: Something doesn't seem right here. Both `DateTime` instances should be created with the same timezone (the system default). The `$date` should be midnight, Tuesday 16th January in that timezone. See https://3v4l.org/j4sL4

Comment: @Phil yeah, it was working fine locally but the server time is in UTC.

Comment: Ah, so the date `20240116` is meant to be in a particular timezone. You should pass full ISO 8601 strings instead of just the date part, ie `2024-01-16T00:00:00-05:00`

Comment: Also, you can change the server's default timezone using `date_default_timezone_set()`

Comment: @Phil thank you so much for the additional context, appreciate it!